# Renaming same file into each subfolder

Tags: unix, rename

What I need to do is the following: let's say that in my folder "folder" I have a bunch of subfolders "001" "002" etc, in each of these subfolders there's a file named "a.dat" wich I want to rename into "b.dat". Can I rename them all in one shot?

It ashames me to ask this question since there are MANY similar to this, however I couldn't find the answer I'm looking for, nor anything that could make me "guess" my answer based on other entries.
For sure a top-down study of the "find" command would answer my question but it would take an exaggerated amount of time for such a simple thing.

Many thanks,

Tom

Comment: Are the names of the subdirectories consecutive?

Comment: Err somehow, the actual names of the directories are slightly more complicated than that, like "a1b1" "a1b2" "a1b3" "a2b1" "a2b2" "a2b3".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
find folder -name a.dat -execdir mv {} b.dat \;
```

The `-execdir` option is like `-exec`, except it first changes to the directory containing the file. So you don't have to worry about merging the filename into the directory, because it's always the current directory.